# ActiveMQ and PHP on web browser

Tags: php, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have been trying to use Active MQ with PHP, while I have been able to run a producer and consumer via a command line PHP script. I wanted to run it in a browser. I'm using the following code :

```
$queue  = '/test/queue';
        $msg    = $data;            
        try {
            $stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');

            $stomp->send($queue, $msg." ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            sleep(1);

        } catch(StompException $e) {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();

        }

        //subscribe to queue
        $stomp->subscribe($queue);

        /* read a frame */
        $frame = $stomp->readFrame();

        if ($frame->body === $msg) {
            echo $frame;

            /* acknowledge that the frame was received */
            $stomp->ack($frame);
        }

        /* close connection */
        unset($stomp);
```

On the Active MQ web interface I'm able to see that a message in the queue is received, but it doesn't get dequeued and nothing is displayed on the browser screen. Am I doing anything wrong?

To give a background - I am trying to build a queuing system where requests from customers can be put inside a queue and the output is delivered after the queue processes the request.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your browser ? A browser can not directly talk to a remote activemq server !

Comment: Yup I got that. But how to show the output to the user?

Comment: see this example from Atmosphere : tweeter live feed https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/twitter-live-feed

Comment: Thanks! that simplifies a lot of things.